# Recursion limit reached in a list of recursive functions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, recursion, procedural-programming

Here is a fragment of the code I was working on the other day, that is constructed from a recursive function with Memorization, whose input is prepared in a For loop and then modified as a boundary condition (depending on what I want).

```
n = 5; (*number of cycles/steps*)
For[i = -n - 1, i <= n + 1, i++,
 f[i, 0] = {{0}, {0}}]
f[0, 0] = {{1}, {0}};
f[x_, t_] := 
  f[x, t] = 
   N[{1/Sqrt[2] {1, 1}.f[x - 1, t - 1], 
     1/Sqrt[2] {1, -1}.f[x + 1, t - 1]}];
l = Table[f[i, n], {i, -n, n}]
```

The resulting list l does have values that are correct, but everything works only up to n=3, for a larger n I get "$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of...". My natural reaction was to increase Recursion limit using

```
$RecursionLimit=12000
```

but it didn't help, and for values of 20000 and larger the code just stops working without any error or beep. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You make a call outside of the range bounded by your termination conditions. E.g. `f[5,1]` calls `f[6,0]` and then hell breaks lose. You can fix that by extending your `For` loop by several steps to the left and to the right.

You can even skip the whole loop if you use the following:

```
ClearAll[f]
n = 5;
f[n_, 0] = {{0.}, {0.}};
f[0, 0] = {{1.}, {0.}};
q = 1./Sqrt[2.];
f[x_, t_] := f[x, t] = {{q, q}.f[x - 1, t - 1], {q, -q}.f[x + 1, t - 1]};
l = Table[f[i, n], {i, -n, n}]
```

> {{{0.}, {0.176777}}, {{0.}, {0.}}, {{-0.176777}, {0.353553}}, {{0.},
>   {0.}}, {{0.}, {-0.353553}}, {{0.}, {0.}}, {{0.}, {0.353553}}, {{0.},
>   {0.}}, {{0.707107}, {0.176777}}, {{0.}, {0.}}, {{0.176777}, {0.}}}

Comment: Yep, that works, but didn't I account for that in the original code by extending the range by n+1 and n-1 from both sides? Is extending it to plus minus 2n really necessary? The values of n in the final version of the program will be really large.

Comment: I found a simpler solution. See my edit.